# import speech_recognition as sr doesn't work on Mac?

Tags: python, macos

import speech_recognition as sr I am trying to program a personal assistance for learning but it says command not found. Does anybody know how I can fix that problem? And if this doesnt work on MAC does anybody have an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to do `import speech_recognition as sr` into your terminal, that wont work. (Not sure if that's what you are trying to do or not, the question is a little bit unclear.) It needs to be in a python file and executed.

If it is in a python file and you are running it via `python code.py` then the error *could* be that you don't have the module (I doubt this because normally it throws a "Module not found" error), but you could try `sudo pip install speech_recognition`.